# Matlab counting the distance

Tags: matlab

I have a problem in computing the distance between two different matrices. The first matrix is `5000x6`, the second matrix is `5x80`.

I want to use this syntax to calculate the distances:

```
pdist2(mCe(1,:),row);
```

But this gives me an error saying "columns in x have to be same in y".

Is there a way to compute the distances when the matrices have a different amount of columns?

Comment: Sorry, what? You're asking something like: "What's the distance between the Earth and a square?"

Comment: What do you understand to be the distance between `[1 2 3 4]` and `[-5 6]`? It's not defined mathematically, so you'll have to be a bit more clear...What do you hope to get out of the calculation?

Answer (score 4):

The `pdist2` function calculates the distance between a set of points based on a metric. A metric is a function of 2 vector arguments from the **same metric space** and as such they are required to have the same dimension. What you want to do is not possible based on the definition of a metric. Read this link for more details

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space

Comment: simply friends 
I am trying to count the distance between two data set first data set contain 6 culomns with more than 5000 rows but the other data set contain like 106 culomns with sample real numbers

Comment: simply friends 
I am trying to count the distance between two data set first data set contain 6 columns with more than 5000 rows but the other data set contain like 106 columns with sample real numbers is it possople to find the distance between those data set , by the way i wanna fine the distance to classify the data whether thay are normal or attack .

Comment: here is an example , please if any one can understand it explain it for me 
clc
clear all
load mC; % from the anal1 execution
load(M)% from the aiNet execution
load ('X.txt');
NZ1=nonzeros(mC(1,:));
count1=size(NZ1,1);
for i=1:count1
ab1(i,:)=M(NZ1(i),:);
end
ab1;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
w=X;
l=w(:,1:end-1);
D1= dist(l,ab1');
[row1,col1]=size(D1);

for i=1:row1
    min_value(i)=2;
    for j=1:col1
        if D1(i,j)<min_value(i)
            min_value(i)=D1(i,j);
    mind1(i)=min_value(i);
    mind11=mind1';